# More variables in constraints than in quadratic objective function

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Assume we have the following quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac{1}{2} x^T Q x \\ \text{subject to} & Ax <b\end{array}$$

This works when the number of constraint variables is equal to the number of objective variables. But let us now assume that

$$x = (x_0,x_1,x_2)$$

but that our objective does not involve $x_0$, in other words we could say that

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0&0\\
0 & Q_{11} & Q_{12}\\
0 & Q_{21} & Q_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix is now not positive definite, and most QP solvers don't work with this. So how should the problem be approached if the minimization function does not involve some variable $x_0$, but the constraint equations *do* involve this variable?

Comment: Either, express $x_0$ as a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and restate it like that, or set $Q_{0,0}$ to a very small value to ensure positive definiteness. The program in its current shape has infinitely many solutions that all minimize the cost function.

Comment: @Petrus1904 I ended up setting it to a very small value and the results were good, please add it as an answer :)

Comment: Your situation is typical and all QP solvers will work with that. Show me one that doesn't.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek for illustration, I use the Python `qpsolvers` library, it will not proceed if the matrix `Q` is not positive definite

Comment: Of all the solvers that package supports only quadprog really seems to require strict positive definiteness. Mosek, OSQP easily consume a semidefinite matrix when called through qpsolvers, and I suppose so would Gurobi. ECOS can't be called but that's also due to a qpsolvers limitation. Use the solvers directly, or cvxpy if you want a nice interface to many solvers.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation has infinitely many solutions that minimize the cost function (ie any value for $x_0$ that satisfies the constraint). To ensure an unique solution can be computed, either express $x_0$ as a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and replace $x_0$ as a variable, or make $Q$ positive definite by setting a very small value for $Q_{0,0}$, like
$$\begin{bmatrix}10^{-8} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_{1,1} & Q_{1,2} \\  0 & Q_{2,1} & Q_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}$$

That should ensure that there exist an unique solution that minimizes the cost function, while simultaneously weighting $x_0$ as minimal as possible.